# jackd cannot use real-time scheduling within docker container

Tags: linux, docker, audio, webrtc, real-time

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get jackd to run with realtime priority within a docker container. My goal is to get SuperCollider audio streaming over the internet using webrtc with help from jackd/gstreamer, and I believe I need realtime scheduling enabled for jackd in order for SuperCollider to use it (this may be a red herring, and maybe SuperCollider doesn't need realtime jackd, but I still want to try this path).

I've had no success on my host machine, a 2014 MacBook Air running macOS 10.13.6, BUT I've also attempted building the image and running the container on an AWS Docker beanstalk application running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.12.16.

Here's a link to the repo with a dockerfile and some README notes with more details/error logs: https://github.com/osetinsky/pulse-streamer/tree/supercollider-example/examples/supercollider

I've spent hours reading similar issues people have had, attempting the following:

- setting `rtprio` and `memlock` within various limits.conf files set in various directories with the appropriate user groups: http://jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html
- updated cgconfig and cgrules for all three of the approaches suggested here: https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/Cgroups
- running docker with realtime scheduler options: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-realtime-scheduler (running with --cap-add=sys_nice --cpu-rt-runtime=950000 --ulimit rtprio=99)

The last approach seemed promising, but fails when I run:

`docker run --privileged --ulimit rtprio=99 --ulimit memlock=800000000 --cpu-rt-runtime=950000 --volume=/dev/shm:/dev/shm:rw --user=1000 -it jack-sc bash`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused 
"process_linux.go:281: applying cgroup configuration for process caused 
\"failed to write 950000 to cpu.rt_runtime_us: write /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker/1bc42e297356c9ad6f734726590c7f42450fcae44e0020950
68b8f10bc93d4f3/cpu.rt_runtime_us: invalid argument\"": unknown.
```

For the record, I *am* able to stream a test tone in realtime with pulseaudio and gstreamer using Pion (a go implementation of webrtc): https://github.com/osetinsky/pulse-streamer

I just want that test tone to be replaced with realtime audio from SuperCollider :)

Similar issues mentioned here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31411

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1178246

(and many more...)

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out – realtime priority was indeed a red herring, at least for my goal of creating a prototype / proof of concept

Comment: the fix was in the startup.scd file used by supercollider – SC_JACK_DEFAULT_OUTPUTS needs to be set to your jackd audio port, which with gstreamer was "in_jackaudiosrc0_1""

Comment: if people want, i can put a more thorough solution here, but i'll need time to revisit it

Comment: Yes, please - a more detailed answer would be very helpful.

Comment: @david A little late to the game here, but I've finally started to open source this:
https://github.com/po-studio/awestruck/tree/chaos

Note, it's broken but I'll be creating issues. You can see a demo in the README